# Change Excel web access dynamically using javascript

Tags: web-part, jquery, excel-services

I have a page with a button and an Excel web part. When I click on the button I want to load another Excel file in that web part.

Is it possible to do this? Please suggest some ideas on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to go with the button function, rather you can use the connected feature of SharePoint.

Follow these steps

1. Create a new Web-Part page.
2. Create a Custom Document Library or you can use the default one's where you can store all the excel workbooks.
3. Then you can add a Excel Web-Part and the Document Library of the Excel workbooks on the newly created Web-Part Page.
4. From the Excel Web Access Web Part, click the Web Part menu  Web Part menu, point to Connections, point to Get Workbook URL From, and then click the appropriate List View Web Part.
5. In the Configure Connection dialog box, select Document URL from the Field Name list box, and then click Finish.
6. Stop Editing the Web-Part Page
7. To view each workbook in the Excel Web Access Web Part, click the option button next to the workbook item in the List View Web Part.

Njoy. For more Information See this [Link](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Connect-a-List-View-Web-Part-to-Excel-Web-Access-1254703e-b366-404d-a5c5-7148d9b8fac6)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That worked, but I have to change only one excel, not list of excels inside a document lib. Even I dont want to expose file names(from doc lib) to the users. So is there any way we can do the same type of connection with button or hyperlink ?